# FCM InvalidRegistration error in ios release build

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a facing a strange issue in ios firebase push notification. I am getting a notification on device whenever I run the app from Xcode or even when I create an archive I am successfully getting notifications.

But when I run a release build on device or upload to app store push notifications are not working for me and I am getting the error below

**Certificates for both development and production are uploaded and are valid.**

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6319718121948146737,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

second time when I call API with same token then instead of `InvalidRegistration` I get `NotRegistered` error

This is how I am generating fcm token

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Pass device token to auth

        #if DEVELOPMENT
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
        #else
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
        #endif

        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true


        //tried this 
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("Firebase registration token: \(token)")

        //tried this also both are giving same token but none of them is 
        //working in release build
        let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")


    }
```

Comment: I never used FCM but this seems like a Sandbox/Production issue, let me know if this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175003/6330448 and you can also refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169460/firebase-push-notifications-not-working-for-production-on-ios

Comment: I have already followed your second link previously but still not helped. I am doing the same way

Comment: try to create production cert without private key, there is nothing you're missing 
 here.

Comment: I tried to send a notification to my APNs device token using APNs certificate but It gave me Invalid device token but in the sandbox environment  it is working perfectly fine @dreamBegin

Comment: Yes, that what i see in most of the question because they were importing there ceritificate with the private key, did you try that excluding your private key?

Comment: yes i tried that way also same error i am getting @dreamBegin

Comment: thats the only thing i found here otherwise your code looks fine to me, here he mentioned the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696152/6330448

Comment: see this issue maybe it'll help you out https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin/issues/122

Comment: now the thing is I got the notification from APNs as well in production envrmnt but still I am not getting notifications from firebase @dreamBegin

Comment: froms APNS the private key will not be a issue in production env but in firebase it does creates problem according to the sources here he say legacy build settings solved his issue https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2518#issuecomment-426244382

Comment: "InvalidRegistration" Clearly specify that you don't have correct FCM token see this here, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html there must be a problem with the firebase configuration and your app.

Comment: but this is the case then it should not work in sandbox mode also but it is working in sandbox mode

Comment: Configuration for sandbox and production may worry at firebase since i didn't use it i can't tell you more about that.

Comment: no that same it is not diffrent at firebase end previously with same code notifications were working for me with sandbox and production from firebase suddenly it stopped working

Comment: that's all i could tell you from here, last suggestion would be to check to repository for the changes when it was working and when it stoped if that remains the same then you know all the problem is from firebase console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I solved this issue by removing this part from my code**

```
 #if DEVELOPMENT
 Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox        
 Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
 #else
 Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
 Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
 #endif
```

Comment: What options have you removed.